# tmux 3.1, copy and paste text within a pane with mouse (Linux, konsole)

Tags: linux, tmux, kde-plasma-5, debian-stretch, konsole

I compiled `tmux` 3.1-rc4 from source per instructions in README (because Debian 9's `tmux` is oldish 2.3):

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/tmux31
make
make install
```

I'm using `tmux` in `konsole` on Debian 9.3, KDE. My `.tmux.conf`:

```
# remap prefix to Control + a
set -g prefix C-a
# bind-key 'C-a C-a' to type 'C-a'
bind-key C-a send-prefix
unbind-key C-b

bind-key -n 'M-Left' select-pane -L
bind-key -n 'M-Down' select-pane -D
bind-key -n 'M-Up' select-pane -U
bind-key -n 'M-Right' select-pane -R

set-option default-terminal tmux

# Linux only
set -g mouse on
bind -n WheelUpPane if-shell -F -t = "#{mouse_any_flag}" "send-keys -M" "if -Ft= '#{pane_in_mode}' 'send-keys -M' 'select-pane -t=; copy-mode -e; send-keys -M'"
bind -n WheelDownPane select-pane -t= \; send-keys -M
bind -n C-WheelUpPane select-pane -t= \; copy-mode -e \; send-keys -M
bind -T copy-mode-vi    C-WheelUpPane   send-keys -X halfpage-up
bind -T copy-mode-vi    C-WheelDownPane send-keys -X halfpage-down
bind -T copy-mode-emacs C-WheelUpPane   send-keys -X halfpage-up
bind -T copy-mode-emacs C-WheelDownPane send-keys -X halfpage-down

# To copy, left click and drag to highlight text in yellow, 
# once you release left click yellow text will disappear and will automatically be available in clibboard
# # Use vim keybindings in copy mode
setw -g mode-keys vi
# Update default binding of `Enter` to also use copy-pipe
unbind -T copy-mode-vi Enter
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi Enter send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "xclip -selection c"
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi MouseDragEnd1Pane send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "xclip -in -selection clipboard"
```

Now, copying to system clipboard with mouse and within one pane *almost* works. When I have two vertical panes, left and right:

- When selecting text in the *left* pane, once I release left mouse button after selecting text, (brownish) selection disappears and the text is copied into system clipboard.
- When selecting text in the *right* pane, once I release left mouse button the selection *stays on* and I have to press `Enter` for selection to be copied successfully to system clipboard. After pressing Enter the (brownish) selection disappears.

**UPDATE**

`tmux` behavior in large `xterm` window is identical as before. The same goes for 80x24 `xterm` window.

When I resize `konsole` window to 80x24, the behavior is also identical as before.

I've checked `TERM` var *before* starting `tmux`, it's `xterm-256color`, it still has no effect on `tmux` behavior.

What's strange is that setting default terminal with `set-option default-terminal` other than `tmux` has no effect, it's always `tmux` no matter what I set.

Good hint with `xclip` setting: redirecting to `/dev/null` has no effect whatsoever! Indeed if I comment out the whole command that uses `xclip`, the behavior stil stays the same.

```
#bind-key -T copy-mode-vi Enter send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "xclip -selection c >/dev/null"
#bind-key -T copy-mode-vi MouseDragEnd1Pane send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "xclip -in -selection clipboard >/dev/null"
```

**UPDATE 2**

OK, I've left only `set -g mouse on` in `.tmux.conf` and the behavior is identical as before (i.e. "wrong").

I've discovered what triggers "wrong" behavior: *leaving the text cursor in the left pane*.

I was copying the text from either pane without moving the text cursor to the right pane. If I move the text cursor to the right pane, the behavior is correct (i.e. selection copies and disappears, pressing Enter is not necessary)!

What's still weird though is that if I keep cursor in the right pane and select text in the left pane, the behavior is "correct" in the sense it copies the selection to clipboard and selection disappears immediately.

Can it be simply a bug in `tmux` RC version?

**UPDATE 3**

Sorry for all the confusion. I think I finally discovered what's the actual problem. What I didn't notice is where exactly I release the left mouse button.

Best see it on screenshots. Nothing but `set -g mouse on` left in `.tmux.conf`.

When I start selecting text in the **right** pane and release the mouse button in the **left** pane:

[image: Copying in the right pane]

When I start selecting text in the **right** pane and release the mouse button in the **right** pane:

[image]

When I start selecting text in the **left** pane and release the mouse button **outside the window to the left**:

[image]

When I start selecting the text in the **left** pane and release the mouse button in the **right** pane:

[image]

So it seems that it's crossing the vertical "text" bar dividing the panes when selecting the text with mouse cursor that causes this behavior (text selection staying on until pressing Enter).

Answer (score 1):

That is very odd.

How big is your terminal? Some terminals do not support the mouse beyond column 223. Does it work with a smaller terminal (say 80x24) or with xterm?

Does it make any difference if you redirect xclip's stdout to `/dev/null` (`xclip -in -selection clipboard >/dev/null`)?

Comment: See UPDATE pls.

Comment: I don't understand your update - do you mean it WORKS if your Konsole is 80x24, or it is the same and doesn't work? How big is your terminal normally? If the terminal doesn't support SGR mouse mode then it won't work with terminals wider than 223 columns - are you sure you were using 2.3 before and not 2.1? Support for large terminals without SGR mouse mode was removed in tmux 2.2.

Comment: I've uninstalled Debian-shipped tmux before doing all this. Basically it didn't matter at all whether I was using either `xterm` or `konsole`, large window or 80x24, the behavior was still problematic like I initially described.

Comment: Anyway, pls see UPDATE 2.

Comment: Just FYI, in my maximized konsole window: `% stty size                                                                                                                                                                                           
56 211`.

Comment: How do you select text without moving the cursor to the pane? By default the root `MouseDrag1Pane` will select the pane so how do you get the cursor back to the left pane without releasing the mouse and stopping the drag?

Comment: Never mind, I think I see what you mean - you are releasing the mouse when the MOUSE cursor is in the other pane, right?

Comment: " you are releasing the mouse when the MOUSE cursor is in the other pane, right" - no. I'm releasing the mouse always in the same pane. The wrong behavior is triggered when the TEXT cursor is in the left pane. When I select the text with MOUSE in the RIGHT pane when the TEXT cursor is in the RIGHT pane, the behavior is correct.

Comment: How do you move the text cursor back to the left pane after you start the drag in the right pane?

Comment: I'm not dragging the text between the panes at all (not yet anyway since I only started learning tmux). Primarily I need copying the text selected in tmux to the *system* clipboard so that I can use it in another application.

Comment: No, I mean you say the problem occurs when you release the mouse, but the text cursor is still in the other pane. But by default when you start dragging tmux will select the pane first, so the text cursor will be in the pane you are dragging (the right pane). So how do you get the text cursor back to the left pane? Is the text cursor not moving to the right pane at all when you start dragging in Konsole? Is it moving in xterm?

Comment: I think Konsole is not sending the mouse down before the drag is started, or tmux is not sending the copy command to the right pane. I need to see tmux logs to see what you are doing and what Konsole is sending, can you open an issue at https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/new please? When you open the issue please run `tmux -Ltest -f/dev/null new` then do `tmux set -g mouse on`, then reproduce the problem in as few steps as possible then exit tmux and attach the `tmux-server-*.log` file from the current directory to the issue.

Comment: I think I actually discovered the cause now, I'm sorry for all the confusion. Writing another update.

Comment: Pls see UPDATE 3.

Comment: OK, so you are releasing the mouse over a different pane from where you started dragging or outside tmux entirely. There isn't much tmux can do if you release it outside tmux entirely and I don't think it is inconsistent to make it behave the same if you release it outside the pane, so I am inclined to say this is just how it works now even if it used to behave differently in 2.3...

Comment: Yes, and I can live with this. As they say in IBM, "it works as designed".

Comment: Well, theoretically, tmux could copy the selection and make it disappear if left mouse button were released in another pane (making behavior identical as when mouse button is released outside terminal window).

Comment: Most terminals don't tell tmux when the mouse button is released outside the terminal window, so it would be different on those terminals.